# PHP Style Guide Conformance

Tags: php, coding-style

For a new project I've just started, I thought it might be a good idea to adhere to a styleguide for my code. I had sort of settled on a style for myself, but could use a little more structure, since there were a few things that varied between my projects and even sometimes within projects.

Now I've settled on this styleguide: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/

Question is though, it says to limit lines of code to 80 characters, so I set up a ruler at that limit in ST3. I'm just not sure what a good practice is in regard to splitting code over multiple lines. How would you split the code below (it's already indented by 8 spaces)?

```
$this->errorMessage = (isset($this->errorDefinitions[$errorNo])) ? $this->errorDefinitions[$errorNo] : $errorMessage;
```

Or would it be better to conform to the guide by abandoning the shorthand expression and just writing:

```
if (isset($this->errorDefinitions[$errorNo])) {
    $this->errorMessage = $this->errorDefinitions[$errorNo];
} else {
    $this->errorMessage = $errorMessage;
}
```

There's nothing in the styleguide on this subject. Can anyone point me in the right direction or just tell me where I can find more information on the 'proper' way of doing it. I realize there might not be consensus on the way to do it, but I'd like to read your opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could break up your shorthand across lines:

```
$this->errorMessage = isset($this->errorDefinitions[$errorNo])
    ? $this->errorDefinitions[$errorNo] 
    : $errorMessage;
```

Just keep in mind that shorthand ternary statements are awesome... when they are short and simple! But once your conditions become longer you are just making your code harder to read, understand, and ultimately maintain. That's why PSR-2 has the line limit (in part).

Your code is a bit in the fuzzy area from my perspective. Breaking it up like above is ok, but if it was any more complicated at all (called a function, etc) I'd say abandon the shorthand and go with the `if`.

Ultimately it's your call, as you pointed out PSR-2 doesn't land on this issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I can at least justify this for myself ;-) I just read that PHP7 actually has a 'null coalescing operator' (??) that will make this statement much shorter and since I'm running this project on a box with PHP7, I'm considere switching this particular statement to that. Your answer is still really useful for future cases though. Thanks!